# How to pass Chrome options in webdriver-user-agent gem for watir

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir, user-agent

I am trying to pass cookies option for Chrome Drive using Watir gem

From Watir documentation i can do `Watir::Browser.new :chrome, opts`

So for cookies I can do:

```
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {args: ['--user-data-dir=/cookies']}
```

When using the webdriver-user-agent gem for mobile testing, their documentation tells me to start the browser like this:

```
driver = Webdriver::UserAgent.driver(browser: :chrome, agent: :iphone)
browser = Watir::Browser.new driver
```

But now I don't know how I can pass the option for the Chrome